# Permissions issue when updating current page properties programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a publishing page that represents a person (a contact form, if you will), and i want to give the user the possibility to edit some of the information in the form (name, age, location...).

So i have an edit button that opens a pop-up windows with the properties i allow the user to update.

Now the problem: when the user presses the save button, an exception is thrown, saying the user does not have permissions to update the page. This happens when i try to either checkout or update the page

My code is this:

```
    Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
            Guid webId = SPContext.Current.Web.ID;
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
           {
               //SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

               using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
               {
                   using (SPWeb currentWeb = site.OpenWeb(webId))
                   {
                       currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                       PublishingPage pubPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(SPContext.Current.ListItem);
                       pubPage.CheckOut();

                       pubPage.ListItem["EdificioContacto"] = dpEdificio.SelectedValue.ToString();
                       pubPage.ListItem["ExtensaoContacto"] = txtExtensao.Text;
                       pubPage.ListItem["FaxContacto"] = txtFax.Text;

                       pubPage.Update();


                       pubPage.ListItem.File.CheckIn("Alteracão de dados de utilizador. Processo automático");
                       pubPage.ListItem.File.Publish("Alteracão de dados de utilizador. Processo automático");
                       pubPage.ListItem.File.Approve("Alteracão de dados de utilizador. Processo automático");

                       currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                   }
               }
```

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** My exception is "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack".

I had this exception before on another class, but it was solved by using the webId and siteId to open the site and web, so i thought that that would solve it was well.

**EDIT2:** I noticed that this situation also happens when i try to programmatically add an item to a sharepoint list while logged in with a "common" user.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [Edit State of page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/57047f04-06cf-44d7-99e5-667182e12605/)

check this code snippet: *check the 'ForceCheckout'*

```
SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.ListItem;
//we cannot modify the page if we have a current item whos parent list has ForceCheckout set and the items file isn't checked out
bool canModifyPage = !(item != null && item.File != null && item.ParentList != null &&
item.ParentList.ForceCheckout && item.File.CheckOutStatus == SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus.None);
```

may be this will also help you in your code:
[Get PageLayout Name in Sharepoint but having a performance issue](http://www.dewani.net/index.php/blog/get-pagelayout-name-in-sharepoint-but-having-a-performance-issue/)

**Edit:**  check this with `currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;`.

Ref:[PublishingPage.CheckOut Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingpage.checkout.aspx)

```
// Get the PublishingPage wrapper for the SPListItem that was passed in.
            //
            PublishingPage publishingPage = null;
            if (PublishingPage.IsPublishingPage(listItem))
            {
                publishingPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(listItem);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("This SPListItem is not a PublishingPage", "listItem");
            }


            // Check out the page if it is not checked out yet.
            //
            if (publishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutStatus == SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus.None)
            {
                publishingPage.CheckOut();
            }


            // Set and save some properties on the PublishingPage.
            //
            publishingPage.Title = newTitle;
            publishingPage.Description = newDescription;
            publishingPage.Contact = pageContact;
            publishingPage.Update();
```

Compare it's page property access method and your.. if anything wrong over there then check for it..

```
 pubPage.ListItem["EdificioContacto"] = dpEdificio.SelectedValue.ToString();
 pubPage.ListItem["ExtensaoContacto"] = txtExtensao.Text;
 pubPage.ListItem["FaxContacto"] = txtFax.Text;
```

Hope this help..

Comment: the bool returns false. As for the second link, it did not launch an exception, but the properties of the page were not getting updated.

Comment: try PublishingPage.CheckOut Method documentation example.. may be it will solve your problem.

Comment: No dice, the condition "publishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutStatus == SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus.None" is true, and so it tries to checkOut the page, but an exception is thrown in that instruction...

Comment: SPListItem item = (SPListItem)SPContext.Current.Item;

Comment: try this `SPListItem item = (SPListItem)SPContext.Current.Item; item[""EdificioContacto"] ="xxxx"` rather than `pubPage.ListItem["EdificioContacto"]` [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/a162e137-0417-4de0-a2f7-8f2583400137)

Comment: The exception is not thrown, but the values aren't saved if i do that. And if i try to do item.update(), the exception is thrown. Not only that, i noticed that the same thing happens when i try to insert a new item in a sharepoint list programmatically with a common user...